# Get the user with the 1000th point (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql, select-query

I am trying to just do a query that will illustrate which student from school_id 1 has got the 1000th point - in this case it is 'Sharon'

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# id # school_id # student # points #
#  1 #     1     #  Harry  #   100  #
#  2 #     1     #  Bob    #   200  #
#  3 #     1     #  Jamie  #   150  #
#  4 #     1     #  Lee    #   200  #
#  5 #     1     #  John   #   200  #
#  6 #     1     #  Sharon #   170  #
#  7 #     2     #   Tim   #  2000  #
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I had a crack with the following query but it doesn't return what I would expect:

```
SELECT
  SUM(points) as pointSum, student
FROM testing
GROUP BY school_id;
```

I would expect a result like this...

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# id # school_id # student # pointsSum #
#  6 #     1     #  Sharon #   1020    #
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Could you outline the expected result.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function

Comment: This doesn't feel like set logic to me.  It has more iterative, procedural feel.  I'd recommend doing this with a stored procedure.

Comment: But sharon has only 170 points. Did she cheat? :(

Comment: Sssh.. she did but nobody must know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table to calculate `SUM` of points for a user and the preceding users (id-wise).

```
select name, sumpoints
from 
(
select id, name, (select sum(points) from tablename t2
                  where t2.id <= t1.id) sumpoints AND t2.school_id = 1
from tablename t1
) dt
where sumpoints >= 1000
order by id
limit 1
```

Comment: Your first query did the trick! Thanks

select * from testing t1
where (select sum(points) from testing t2
       where t2.id <= t1.id) >= 1000
order by id
limit 1

Comment: Ok - this edited query by @Thorsten works 100% perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for editing. (I missed that school_id = 1 requirement.)